# Projection $\pi: \mathbb{P}^n \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ away from center $p$ maps

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, projective-schemes, projective-varieties

Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective variety and
$p \in \mathbb{P}^n$ an arbitrary point not contaned
in $X$. The rational projection with center $p$ map
$\pi: \mathbb{P}^n \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ can be
described precisely by $x=(x_0:x_1:...:x_n) \mapsto
(Y_1(x): ... : Y_n(x))$ where $Y_i = \sum_{j=0}^n a_{ij} X_j$
are linear functions with $p= V(Y_1,...,Y_n)$.

Since one assumes $p \not \in X$ the restriction of $\pi$
to $X$ gives a regular map $p: X \to \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ with
image $I = p(X)$.

Question: Do such restricted projection with center $p$ maps
share important general properties as maps maps
of varieties? For example is the image $p(X)$ always closed?
Or say is $p$ always a closed map? What about smoothness?

Now let consider a special case: Assume that
$\operatorname{dim}(X)=n-1$. Let $x \in X$ a smooth point
and $p$ is choosen in a way that:

a) $p \not \in X$ as before

b) $p \not \in T_x X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$

The tangent space $T_x X$ in $x$ lives naturally in $\mathbb{P}^n$.
Since we assumed $x \in X$ to be smooth, the subvariety
$T_x X$ is a projective linear subspace of codimension $1$
(ie isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$)
and
now we project away from $p$ onto $T_x X \cong \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$.
Restricting the rational projection
$\pi: \mathbb{P}^n \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$
as before we obtain a map
$p: X \to \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$
which has now some interesting properties. Every
fiber equals a line $l \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ through $p$
intersected with $X$. Since $p \not \in X$, the intersection
$X \cap l$ is finite and therefore this map is finite.

The important question is why assumptions a) and b) on $p$
also imply that $p: X \to \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ is
etale at the point $x$.

(Source: That's what is clamed in 'Algebraic Curves,
Algebraic Manifolds and Schemes' by
V.I. Danilov and V.V. Shokurov
on page 236). link: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540519959

Comment: You can first blowup the point $p$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$, so that $X$ becomes a closed subvariety of the blowup, and then the rational map induces a regular **proper** morphism from the blowup, so that the image of $X$ is the image under a proper morphism.

Comment: I'm not sure if I properly understand your argument. Let me
summarize what I understand (maybe the summary shows my
thinking error). By assumption $X \subset P^n$ and
$p \not \in X$, then we blowup $b:B_p(P^n) \to P^n$.
Therefore the blow up maps isomorphically $b^{-1}(X) \to X$, ie
we can assume that $X \cong b^{-1}(X)$ is contaned in
$B_p(P^n)$. But then you are talking about a 'certain
rational map' which induces a regular proper morphism from the blowup.
Which 'rational map' do you mean at this point?

Comment: my guess: The composition of
$b$ restricted to $b^{-1}(X)$ composed with restricted projection
$p: X \to \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ from above? Or something else?

Comment: another point: what is the advantage here to use the
blowing up technique? As far as I can follow you the main goal is
still to show that the restricted projection 
 $p: X \to \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ is proper and it seems that
the reason you involve the blowing up
technique here, is that you use it as a 'tool' to deduce
the properness, right?

Comment: The blowup construction allows to replace a rational map $\mathbb{P}^n \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ or a regular non-proper morphism $\mathbb{P}^n \setminus \{p\} \to \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ by a regular proper morphism $Bl_p(\mathbb{P}^n) \to \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$.

Comment: I think I understand now what you mean. After the 
identification of $X$ with $b^{-1}(X)$ by the blowup
$b:B_p(P^n) \to P^n$ we observe that (up to this isomorphism)
the restricted projection $p: X \to \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ 
comming from rational $P^n \dashrightarrow P^{n-1}$ is
the same as $Bl_p(P^n) \to P^{n-1}$ restricted to
$b^{-1}(X)$, where the $Bl_p(P^n) \to P^{n-1}$ arise
as restriction of canonical proper projection
$P^n \times P^{n-1} \to P^{n-1}$ because 
$Bl_p(P^n) \subset P^n \times P^{n-1}$, that's the argument, right?
Well, and $X \times X \to Y$ are proper

Comment: So generally for all maps $p: X \to \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ which 
arise as restriction of rational projection
$P^n \dashrightarrow P^{n-1}$ from a point the *only* 
property which they share all is that these are proper, that's
all if don't impose some additional assumtions on $X$ and/or
$p$, right?

Comment: And I think I have an answer to the second part of my
question, that's why if we choose as projection 
hyperplane $T_xX$ and $x \in X$ is smooth, then
$p: X \to \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ is etale. 

The book I quoted defines a morphism $f: X \to Y$ as etale in $x \in X$
if the induced map $df_x: C_xX \to C_{f(x)}Y$ on *tangent
cones* is an isomorphism. Here $x$ smooth means
$C_xX= T_xX$ and literally by construction the projection
$p$ induces $dp_x = id$ on $T_xX$.